# Pandas: How to flag a column with groupy & apply()

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Right now, my code will return the rows that meet the condition in my function. How can I instead return all original rows and flag a new column ('GreaterDate) if the condition is true?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'KEY': ['100000003', '100000009', '100000009', '100000009', '100000009','100000034','100000034', '100000034'], 
          'Date1': [20120506, 20120506, 20120507,20120608,20120620,20120206,20120306,20120506],
          'Date2': [20120528, 20120507, 20120615,20120629,20120206,20120305,20120506,20120506]})

def date_compare(df):
    date_before  = df['Date1'].shift(-1)
    value = df[df['Date2'] == date_before]
    return value

dftest = df.groupby('KEY').apply(date_compare)
dftest
```

This returns two true values.

```
                Date1      Date2        KEY
KEY             
100000009   1   20120506    20120507    100000009
100000034   6   20120306    20120506    100000034
```

I've tried using

```
dftest['GreaterDate'] = df.groupby('KEY').apply(date_compare)
```

but that doesn't work. 
Im not so interested in the date function working, I merely used this function as an example. I am more interested in how to use apply on a groupby in order to add a new column with True or False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
def date_compare(df):
    df['dftest'] = df['Date2'] == df['Date1'].shift(-1)
    return df

dftest = pd.concat([df[df.KEY == k].pipe(date_compare) \
                   for k in set(df.KEY)], ignore_index=True)

#       Date1     Date2        KEY  dftest
# 0  20120506  20120507  100000009    True
# 1  20120507  20120615  100000009   False
# 2  20120608  20120629  100000009   False
# 3  20120620  20120206  100000009   False
# 4  20120206  20120305  100000034   False
# 5  20120306  20120506  100000034    True
# 6  20120506  20120506  100000034   False
# 7  20120506  20120528  100000003   False
```

Comment: I edited the example df. The only issue with this approach is that it ignores the groups, when I need it to stay within the group.